How to use Llama3?
I'm using Ollama and llama 3 to build a ChatBot. However, right now, it can't remember chat history. For example, if my first query is "tell me about the theory of relativity," and if my next query is "can you simplify it," it throws a message saying it can't recall earlier conversations.
Here is my current code snippet:
import ollama
import streamlit as st

# function to get the llama's response
def get_llama_response(prompt):
    response = ollama.chat(
        model='llama3',
        messages= [
            {
                'role':'user',
                'content': prompt
            }
        ]
    )
    return response['message']['content']

# setting the title
st.title("Llama Knows All")

# loading message and we take prompt
prompt = st.chat_input("How can I help you today?")

# setting up a session to hold all messages during current interaction
if 'messages' not in st.session_state:
    st.session_state.messages = []

# displaying older messages
for message in st.session_state.messages:
    st.chat_message(message['role']).markdown(message['content'])

if prompt:
    # display the user message
    st.chat_message('user').markdown(prompt)
    st.session_state.messages.append({'role':'user', 'content': prompt})

    llama_response = get_llama_response(prompt)

    st.chat_message('llama').markdown(llama_response)
    st.session_state.messages.append({'role': 'llama', 'content': llama_response})


your get_llama_response function is not passing the history at all, you can try the correction below
def get_llama_response():
  response = client.chat(
      model=MODEL,
      messages=st.session_state.messages,
  )
  return response["message"]

